# Merge objects with same keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have several objects that look like this when i console.log them:

```
0: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
1: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
2: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
```

and

```
0: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }
1: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }
```

I am looking to combine these objects so that they become like:

```
0: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
1: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
2: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
3: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }
4: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }
```

But when I use something like `Object.assign` the last object will just overwrite the previous one, is there another method to do this? I basically just want to merge several objects, and ignore their indexes.

Comment: they look like arrays, not objects. Array.concat would be used for that

Comment: If you don't care about the keys, just make them an array: `const foo = [...Object.values(obj1), ...Object.values(obj2)]`

Comment: push them all in one array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you have is an array.

You can use the spread operator.

Let's call your two arrays `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` respectively.

The code would be:

`const newArray = [...arrayOne, ...arrayTwo];`

Comment: One quible, OP gave objects, you need to call `Object.values` like in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const arr1 = [
 { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} },
 { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} },
 { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }
]

const arr2 = [
 { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} },
 { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }
]

const result = [...arr1, ...arr2]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @nxmohamad beat you to the punch.

Comment: @JaredSmith 50 seconds late :P , but `Object.values` is more accurate anyways

Comment: lol technically I beat him by 15 seconds, but I just left it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [{ 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} },
{ 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} },
{ 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }];

var array2 = [ { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} },
{ 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }];

while(array2.length>0){
array1.push(array2.shift());
}
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the values of the objects and assign the array to an object.

```js
var obj1 = { 0: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }, 1: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} }, 2: { 'school': {}, 'district': {}, 'children': {} } },
    obj2 = { 0: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} }, 1: { 'teacher': {}, 'name': {}, 'class': {} } };
    obj3 = Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj1).concat(Object.values(obj2)));

console.log(obj3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```